# Remove and replace consecutive characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I have that content:

```
ALL&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;EVERYTHING
```

I want to remove all `&nbsp;` and get that string: `ALL EVERYTHING`.

If I use that code:

```
  var str = $("#post_wall_textarea_parent .emojionearea-editor").html(); // I can't use $("#post_wall_textarea_parent .emojionearea-editor").text(); for many reasons
  str_  = str.replace(/&nbsp;/g, " ");
```

It gives me that: `ALL                                  EVERYTHING`.

I want to remove more thant one space between two words.

How could I do to get: `ALL EVERYTHING` instead of `ALL                                  EVERYTHING`. ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an example of the animated png? Or what makes you think it is a png?

Comment: @zagbala What if someone doesn\`t have a Facebook account (me, for example)? Anyway, the PNG you see may probably be an [APNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG).

Comment: as you do with the rest .replace(”  ”, ” ”) replace 2spaces with one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.replace(/(&nbsp;)+/g, " ");`

```js
const str = "ALL&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;EVERYTHING";

const result = str.replace(/(&nbsp;)+/g, " ");

console.log(result);
```

`Edited as Dimitri's Comment.

Comment: This code is not correct. `[&nbsp;]` will look for any character in the the braces so it will also change `&nbssssssssp;` and just the characters `&`, `;`, `n`, `b`, `s `, `p`. The regular expression needs to be `/(&nbsp;)+/g`

Comment: @DimitriL. I agree, updated the answer as per the comment.